# Using a specific rvm gemset and letting it persists until changed

Tags: rvm

```
rvm gemset list

==> (default)
proj1
proj2
...
```

I can switch the gemsets to proj1 by `rvm gemset use proj1` but once I open a new bash tab/window, the rvm switches back to default. How do I make it persist until I decided to switch to a different gemset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every terminal window / tab is a new subprocess with its own copy of environment and it can not influence parent process. It is not possible to set current loaded gemset that will be persisted between tabs without setting default.

The default is set for ruby and can include gemset:

```
rvm use 1.9.3@project --default
```

the `--default` flag sets default which is loaded with rvm when there was no other ruby loaded before.